# Do we need unit length eigenvectors for the process of matrix diagonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I diagonalized a 2 by 2 matrix recently, and I did the usual process:

Find eigenvectors of the matrix $A$, put those column vectors together side by side to form a new matrix $S$, then compute $S^{-1}AS$, which is diagonal.

During this process, I usually take unit length eigenvectors but for the 2 by 2 matrix case, this is not necessary, and I can multiply the used eigenvectors by any nonzero scalar.

Is this the case for the not 2 by 2 matrices as well? If yes, that makes life much easier in some cases.

Comment: Btw you don't need to compute $S^{-1}$ in order to find $D=S^{-1}AS$. If you've done everything right then $D$ is simply the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal (in places corresponding to the position of the eigenvectors in $S$.) You can check the whole thing by verifying that $SD=AS$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to take eigenvectors. They don't have to have norm $1$.